# How can I prevent a redirect via custom controller?

Tags: magento-enterprise, controllers, redirect, redirect-url

I have a custom form with an action that calls my module controller, I would like to prevent the redirect and stay on the page where the form is submitted but when I try to add a wildcard in my controller index action I get a 'too many redirects error'

`$this->_redirect('*/*/');`

I've also tried

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

And

```
$this->_redirectReferer('*/*/');
```

Here is my index Action in my module controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($params['country'])) {
        $this->setCountry((string)$params['country'], isset($params['hide']));
    }

    if (isset($params['currency'])) {
        $this->setCurrency((string)$params['currency']);
    }
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

And below is my form which posts to my controller

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('locale/switch'); ?>">
    ....
</form>
```

Is there a better way to have this form submit without redirecting to the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer doesn't involve forcing Magento to stay on the page since

```
$this->_redirectReferer()
```

Handles this behaviour nicely for us. The problem itself was due to some pages having a secure URL which meant that Magento would redirect when the form was submitted over `https` the solution was to change:

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('locale/switch'); ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('locale/switch',array('_secure'=>true)); ?>
```

Now the form can be submitted over secure and unsecure URLs without redirecting